# Rails 3 Paperclip with file upload/downloads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a rails 3 app that allows users to share files by uploading them to Amazon s3 via paperclip, and I want to allow others users to download these files.  However, some sort of post-processing seems to be going on with this file somewhere between my app and Amazon s3.

Here's my code:

```
  has_attached_file :attachment,
                    :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml", 
                    :path => ':id/:style', :bucket => "test_development"
```

This works fine, however if I actually go to the amazon s3 developer tools the url for the file just seems to be: http://s3.amazonaws.com/test_development/1/original without the original name or type.

I then tried using something like this: `[p.attachment.url(:original, false), p.attachment_file_name].join("/")`

which yields: http://s3.amazonaws.com/test_development/1/original/test.pdf

However if I got to this url I get a cryptic xml error:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>1/original/About Downloads.pdf</Key>
<RequestId>7E5CC6A01CADF831</RequestId>
<HostId>
4ruFf0JtdalnaIE/SHUAqT8hVYEda9Ul6gxNmYTIAniw7piTN+Q16uKKCzi9yezl
</HostId>
</Error>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I just want to upload the file to s3 without any sort of processing then download again later..how should I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:path` option is is used as the full filename. Nothing is added, it's only interpolated. Try `:path => ':id/:style/:basename.:extension'`.

And when you change `:path`, you often have to change `:url` also.

More infos:

- http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Storage/S3
- http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Storage/Filesystem
- http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/ClassMethods#has_attached_file-instance_method